# Получить количество элементов в массиве JSON

Tags: c#, json

Использую библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json

Как получить количество элементов в массиве JSON ?

Как делать правильно ?

```
 // загружаю json из string
 JObject respJson = JObject.Parse(resp);

// Пробовал так - чтобы затем взять Count()
IList<JToken> list = respJson["ключ"].Children().ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вам тут `.Children()` и `.ToList()`? Если надо получить просто кол-во объектов, то `int count = respJson["ключ"].Count();` и если `ключ` является массивом, то выдаст кол-во элементов внутри.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо!